# How to add linker option to CMake bootstrap?

Tags: cmake, linker-errors, aix, linker-flags

I'm building CMake 3.12.4 from the release tarball on AIX. CMake is failing to link on the machine:

```
ld: 0711-781 ERROR: TOC overflow. TOC size: 65632  Maximum size: 65536
```

The error is detailed in the IBM technotes at [ld: 0711-781 ERROR: TOC overflow](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21175442). I want to add `-bbigtoc` linker option for the cmake recipe.

CMake's bootstrap does not appear to accept linker options for `LDFLAGS` as shown below.

How do I add a linker flag to the bootstrap process?

---

Here are the options CMake bootstrap accepts:

```
$ ./bootstrap --help

Usage: ./bootstrap [<options>...] [-- <cmake-options>...]
Options: [defaults in brackets after descriptions]
Configuration:
  --help                  print this message
  --version               only print version information
  --verbose               display more information
  --parallel=n            bootstrap cmake in parallel, where n is
                          number of nodes [1]
  --enable-ccache         Enable ccache when building cmake
  --init=FILE             load FILE as script to populate cache
  --system-libs           use all system-installed third-party libraries
                          (for use only by package maintainers)
  --no-system-libs        use all cmake-provided third-party libraries
                          (default)
  --system-curl           use system-installed curl library
  --no-system-curl        use cmake-provided curl library (default)
  --system-expat          use system-installed expat library
  --no-system-expat       use cmake-provided expat library (default)
  --system-jsoncpp        use system-installed jsoncpp library
  --no-system-jsoncpp     use cmake-provided jsoncpp library (default)
  --system-zlib           use system-installed zlib library
  --no-system-zlib        use cmake-provided zlib library (default)
  --system-bzip2          use system-installed bzip2 library
  --no-system-bzip2       use cmake-provided bzip2 library (default)
  --system-liblzma        use system-installed liblzma library
  --no-system-liblzma     use cmake-provided liblzma library (default)
  --system-libarchive     use system-installed libarchive library
  --no-system-libarchive  use cmake-provided libarchive library (default)
  --system-librhash       use system-installed librhash library
  --no-system-librhash    use cmake-provided librhash library (default)
  --system-libuv          use system-installed libuv library
  --no-system-libuv       use cmake-provided libuv library (default)

  --qt-gui                build the Qt-based GUI (requires Qt >= 4.2)
  --no-qt-gui             do not build the Qt-based GUI (default)
  --qt-qmake=<qmake>      use <qmake> as the qmake executable to find Qt

  --sphinx-info           build Info manual with Sphinx
  --sphinx-man            build man pages with Sphinx
  --sphinx-html           build html help with Sphinx
  --sphinx-qthelp         build qch help with Sphinx
  --sphinx-build=<sb>     use <sb> as the sphinx-build executable
  --sphinx-flags=<flags>  pass <flags> to sphinx-build executable

Directory and file names:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install files in tree rooted at PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --bindir=DIR            install binaries in PREFIX/DIR
                          [bin]
  --datadir=DIR           install data files in PREFIX/DIR
                          [share/cmake-3.12]
  --docdir=DIR            install documentation files in PREFIX/DIR
                          [doc/cmake-3.12]
  --mandir=DIR            install man pages files in PREFIX/DIR/manN
                          [man]
  --xdgdatadir=DIR        install XDG specific files in PREFIX/DIR
                          [share]
```

---

Here is the CMake link error:

```
cmake_build$ make VERBOSE=1
...
[ 91%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/cmake
        cd /home/noloader/cmake_build/Source && /home/noloader/cmake_build/Boots
trap.cmk/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/g++  -pthread -Wl,-bnoipath -Wl,-brtl -Wl,-bexpall CMakeFiles/cmake.dir
/cmakemain.cxx.o CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/cmcmd.cxx.o  -o ../bin/cmake -Wl,-blibpath
:/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.8.1/pthread:/opt/freeware/lib/pt
hread:/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.8.1:/opt/freeware/lib:/usr/
lib:/lib libCMakeLib.a libCMakeServerLib.a libCMakeLib.a kwsys/libcmsys.a ../Uti
lities/cmexpat/libcmexpat.a ../Utilities/cmlibarchive/libarchive/libcmlibarchive
.a ../Utilities/cmliblzma/libcmliblzma.a ../Utilities/cmbzip2/libcmbzip2.a ../Ut
ilities/cmcompress/libcmcompress.a ../Utilities/cmcurl/lib/libcmcurl.a ../Utilit
ies/cmzlib/libcmzlib.a -lld ../Utilities/cmjsoncpp/libcmjsoncpp.a ../Utilities/c
mlibuv/libcmlibuv.a -lperfstat ../Utilities/cmlibrhash/libcmlibrhash.a
ld: 0711-781 ERROR: TOC overflow. TOC size: 65632       Maximum size: 65536
collect2: error: ld returned 12 exit status
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
export CFLAGS=...
export CXXFLAGS=...
export LDFLAGS='... -Wl,-bbigtoc'

./bootstrap ... --verbose

make VERBOSE=1 all
```

Also you might want to read this: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0025

Comment: Thanks @Lorinczy. CMake is a different beast. It uses its own options and flags scheme. It does not use standard options and flags. If CMake used standard options it would be easy to use it. Instead everything gets passed as a `-DCMAKE_<SOME_OPT>=..`, which is being ignored during bootstrap.

Comment: @jww Well, if my suggestion didn't work (though it works for me in AIX6.1, cmake-3.11.4), please provide some details, exactly what did your try, and what errors did you get.

Comment: Thanks again Lorinczy. My bad, I was not clear. CMake does not use `CC`, `CXX`, `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`,etc. It has its own way of doing things using preprocessor macros.

Comment: Hi, you might have misunderstood my posts: what I suggested, isn't some random guess, it actually worked for me. Also you should keep in mind that you're building cmake, _not_ building _with_ cmake.

Comment: @jww Any success yet?