# CMake 3 Bootstrapping and g++ problems

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, g++

I am working on a Linux Redhat server. I am trying to Bootstrap my CMake 3 download files as per [How to download, compile, and install CMake on Linux](https://geeksww.com/tutorials/operating_systems/linux/installation/downloading_compiling_and_installing_cmake_on_linux.php).

I changed 2 lines in the bootstrap file so that I would be using the appropriate GCC/G++ versions:

```
# Toolchain compiler name table.
cmake_toolchain_Clang_CC='clang'
cmake_toolchain_Clang_CXX='clang++'
# cmake_toolchain_GNU_CC='gcc'
cmake_toolchain_GNU_CC='/inf/projdig/users/{username}/gcc_install/bin/gcc'
#cmake_toolchain_GNU_CXX='g++'
cmake_toolchain_GNU_CXX='/inf/projdig/users/{username}/gcc_install/bin/g++'
cmake_toolchain_PGI_CC='pgcc'
cmake_toolchain_PGI_CXX='pgCC'
cmake_toolchain_PathScale_CC='pathcc'
cmake_toolchain_PathScale_CXX='pathCC'
cmake_toolchain_XL_CC='xlc'
cmake_toolchain_XL_CXX='xlC'
```

But, it seems like bootstrap is still referencing some compiler-related files in the root directories even though I want it to only reference these:

```
/inf/projdig/users/{username}/gcc_install/bin/gcc  and 
/inf/projdig/users/{username}/gcc_install/bin/g++
```

Please see this error:

[image: Error 1]

What should I change in the Bootstrap file so that nothing in /usr/... is referenced, and only

```
/inf/projdig/users/{username}/gcc_install/bin/gcc and 
/inf/projdig/users/{username}/gcc_install/bin/g++
```

are referenced?

**UPDATE**

Okay, I did manage to fix some problems by specifying 
`-L/{path to correct libstdc++}` compiler option.

However, at the very end of the bootstrap script, this line doesn't work:

[image: Error 2]

I can't just fix it by adding a -L compiler option because this does not invoke a compiler. It's invoking CMake. This command above produces the same error (ie. it searches /usr/lib64 for the libraries, which is the path I don't want it to look through). How can I let CMake look at a different path for libraries? What option should I specify after .../cmake ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to specify additional arguments to CMake during bootstrap. Or I have not been able to find a documented method. Related, see [How to add linker option to CMake bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53472781/608639)